# Symfony PdoSessionHandler session lifetime

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine, symfony4

There is Symfony 4 app with PdoSessionHandler where session duration is supposed to be 10 hours eg 36000 seconds.

```
framework.yaml has: cookie_lifetime:           86400

php.ini has: session.gc_maxlifetime 36000
```

However `sess_lifetime` in `sessions` table is still 1440.

How to make sure that session lifetime would be 10 hours?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this but it would always update the `sess_lifetime` to whatever is stored in `session.gc_maxlifetime`. How have you verified that the php.ini-value is applied in the execution context of your app (not on the console but directly on the webserver)?

Comment: This comment made me debug deeper and see the value from inside Symfony app. Before tested with separate php file displaying phpinfo() in public folder in browser.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out that `framework.yaml` had another parameter that was overwriting `php.ini` value.

Changing this value helped:

```
framework:
    session:
        gc_maxlifetime: 36000
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#gc-maxlifetime